# What's the Common Lisp equivalent of the C function fread?

Tags: c, opengl, common-lisp, fread, sbcl

I'm attempting to port some C code to Common Lisp (details probably irrelevant, but I'm trying to read an rgb image file into a block of memory to bind a texture for use with cl-opengl). The C version of what I'm trying to do is:

```
void * data;
FILE * file;
int bytecount = width * height * 3;
file = fopen ( rgbfilepath, "rb" );
data = malloc( bytecount );
fread( data, bytecount, file);
fclose( file );
//do stuff with data...
```

It has been a few years since I did this, but my understanding of this code is that it is reading a bunch of bytes from the file into the `malloc`-ed memory without paying any attention whatsoever to the content of those bytes.

After some googling, I found http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Read_entire_file#Common_Lisp and http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Read_a_file_into_a_byte_array#Common_Lisp which are very similar. My version looks like

```
(with-open-file (stream rgb-file-path)
  (let ((data (make-string (file-length stream)))
    (read-sequence data stream)
    ;;do stuff with data...
```

When I run this thing on an rgb file, I get the following complaint from SBCL:

```
debugger invoked on a SB-INT:STREAM-DECODING-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10055E6EA3}>:
  :UTF-8 stream decoding error on
  #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM
  for "file /home/john/code/lisp/commonlisp/opengl-practice/wall.rgb"
    {1005A8EB53}>:

    the octet sequence #(218 0) cannot be decoded.
```

My speculative interpretation of this is that the use of `make-string` expects the bytes to be characters, while the rgb file I am loading just has a bunch of bytes, not necessarily valid ASCII or whatever character set is expected. But I could be way off. Any suggestions about how to duplicate what `fread()` does?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this raw, you need to specify an `element-type` to `open` (or `with-open-file`) that is a subtype of `integer` (most likely something like `'(unsigned-byte 8)` so that it is read as octets instead of characters.

I would use a library to read images, though.  I have used `opticl` in the past, which is quite straightforward and uses two- or three-dimensional simple-arrays to represent image data (two dimensions plus one for the colours).

Comment: I will look into opticl for sure, but for now I am just trying to get the same functionality from cl-opengl that I know how to get in C.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Starting now with 
`(setf mystream (open "wall.rgb" :direction :input :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8)))`
 It seems like the next step in this analogy would be to say 
`(setf data (make-sequence '(unsigned-byte 8) (file-length stream)))` 
but this gives me an error 
`(UNSIGNED-BYTE 8) is a bad type specifier for sequences.` 
I'll be back soon if I figure something out.

Comment: Do read the CLHS documentation for the functions you are using.  I recommend using `make-array` here.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Svante for leading me in the right direction. Here is what worked:

```
(setf mystream (open rgb-file-name :direction :input :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8)))
(setf data (make-array (file-length mystream) :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8)))
(read-sequence data mystream)
(close mystream)
```

Comment: If a condition is signalled during the read, the stream will not be closed.  Better use `with-open-file` instead of `open` and `close`.  Also, it looks like you are operating on unbound variables.  I'd expect `let` bindings instead of the `setf` forms.

Comment: So, I propose the following improvement: `(defun read-rgb-file (filename) (with-open-file (mystream filename :direction :input :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8) :if-does-not-exist :error) (let ((data (make-array (file-length mystream) :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8)))) (read-sequence data mystream) data)))`